# SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:self signed certificate aioodbc

Tags: python, ssl

I try to connect to my database using

```
import aioodbc
    
dsn = 'Driver=ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server;Server=my_adress;Database=ML;UID=123;PWD=123;TrustServerCertificate=no'
        connect = partial(aioodbc.connect, dsn=dsn, echo=True, autocommit=True)
```

But after i have following error

```
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:self signed certificate] (-1) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

how to disable ssl verification ?

Comment: Do SQL server machine and client (python) match ODBC Driver version?
I tried downgrading to ODBC 17 and everything worked out